# Portable class library: recommended replacement for [Serializable]

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract, serializable, portable-class-library

I am porting a .NET Framework C# class library to a Portable Class Library. One recurring problem is how to deal with classes decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute, since this attribute is not part of the Portable Class Library subset. Serialization functionality in the Portable Class Library subset instead appears to be covered by [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx).

- To preserve as much of functionality as possible in the Portable Class Library, is it sufficient to replace `[Serializable]` with the `[DataContract]` attribute (with the implication that all fields and properties subject to serialization would need to be decorated with `[DataMember]` as well)?
- What (if anything) will I ***not*** be able to do with this approach that I ***can*** do with `[Serializable]` applied?
- Is there a less intrusive approach?

Given that `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` are used, I am considering to change the code along the following lines. Are there any obvious flaws with this approach? Is there any way to formulate the same thing less verbose?

```
#if PORTABLE
    [DataContract]
#else
    [Serializable]
#endif
    public class SerializableClass : SerializableBaseClass
    {
       ...
#if !PORTABLE
        protected SerializableClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
             : base(info, context)
        {
        }
#endif
        ...
#if PORTABLE
        [DataMember]
#endif
        private Type1 _serializableField;

#if PORTABLE
        [DataMember]
#endif
        private Type2 SerializableProperty { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Portable Class Libraries (PCLs) now officially deprecated** [16 August 2017]

> If you’re sharing code between different .NET implementations today,
>   you’re probably aware of Portable Class Libraries (PCLs). With the
>   release of .NET Standard 2.0, we’re now officially deprecating PCLs
>   and you should move your projects to .NET Standard.

**Source:** [Announcing .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/)

**Portable Class Library (PCL) now available on all platforms [14 Oct 2013]**

> Prior to today’s release, there was a license restriction with the PCL
>   reference assemblies which meant they could only be used on Windows.
>   With today’s release we are announcing a new standalone release of the
>   PCL reference assemblies with a license that allows it to be **used on
>   any platform – including non-Microsoft ones.**  This enables developers
>   even more flexibility and to do great things with .NET.

**Source:** [Portable Class Library (PCL) now available on all platforms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/14/portable-class-library-pcl-now-available-on-all-platforms.aspx)

**Download:** [Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727)

Just for the reference the allowed set of assemblies are:

> mscorlib.dll
>
> System.dll
>
> System.Core.dll
>
> System.Xml.dll
>
> System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll (MEF)
>
> System.Net.dll
>
> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> System.Xml.Serialization.dll
>
> System.Windows.dll (from Silverlight)

As far as I know you need to mark the fields with **DataMember** attribute, and add the **DataContract** attribute.

**UPDATE**

Yes.

You can look how [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) portable class library solution is implemented. You can find the solution in the **Source\Src\Newtonsoft.Json.Portable** when you download the project from here [Json.NET 4.5 Release 10 (source + binary)](http://json.codeplex.com/downloads/get/501717).

Basically they are using an approach with a custom attribute provider

//don't use Serializable

```
#if !(SILVERLIGHT || WINDOWS_PHONE || NETFX_CORE || PORTABLE)
  [Serializable]
#endif
```

//use custom provider

```
#if NETFX_CORE || PORTABLE
using ICustomAttributeProvider = Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CustomAttributeProvider;
#endif
```

And if project is **PORTABLE**

```
#if !PocketPC && !NET20
      DataContractAttribute dataContractAttribute = GetDataContractAttribute(objectType);
      if (dataContractAttribute != null)
        return MemberSerialization.OptIn;
#endif
```

where **OptIn** description is:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Only members must be marked with <see cref="JsonPropertyAttribute"/> or <see cref="DataMemberAttribute"/> are serialized.
    /// This member serialization mode can also be set by marking the class with <see cref="DataContractAttribute"/>.
    /// </summary>
    OptIn,
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE 2**

> Am I losing any abilities using [DataContract] instead of
>   [Serializable], or will I still be able to do everything that
>   [Serializable] supports?

You can do everything that **Serializable** supports except
control over how the object is serialized outside of setting the name and the order.

Using [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) has several benefits:

serialize anything decorated with a `[DataMember]` even if it's not public visible

can't serialize anything unless you specifically tell it to **("opt-in")**

you can define the order in which the elements are serialized using the `[Order=]` attribute on the `[DataMember]`

doesn't require a parameterless constructor for deserialization

is 10% faster than XmlSerializer.

Read more here: [XmlSerializer vs DataContractSerializer](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/)

Also for the reference:

`DataContract` supports serialization of the following kinds of types in the default mode:
CLR built-in types

> Byte array, DateTime, TimeSpan, GUID, Uri, XmlQualifiedName,
>   XmlElement and XmlNode array
>
> Enums
>
> Types marked with DataContract or CollectionDataContract attribute
>
> Types that implement IXmlSerializable
>
> Arrays and Collection classes including List, Dictionary and
>   Hashtable
>
> Types marked with Serializable attribute including those that
>   implement ISerializable
>
> Types with none of the above attributes (POCO) but with a default
>   constructor

Comment: My main concern is; would decoration with [DataContract] and  [DataMember] be sufficient replacements for [Serializable]?

Comment: Many thanks for the informative update, I'll have a closer look at JSON. Am I losing any abilities using [DataContract] instead of [Serializable], or will I still be able to do everything that [Serializable] supports?

Answer (score 10):

One thing you could do to eliminate the clutter that the constant preprocessor directives causes is to push that off to one new `SerializableAttribute` class and basically trick the compiler.

```
#if PORTABLE
namespace System
{
   public class SerializableAttribute : Attribute
   {
       //this does nothing
   }  
}
#endif
```

Then just continue to decorate your classes with `Serializable` as normal...

Comment: Thanks! However, with this solution seriality functionality would be left out, right?

Comment: This doesn't work — there is an exception like "Type *** is not marked as Serializable."

Comment: Hmm... According to this comment https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/71885/#Comment_71885 in the post that linked me here, this should work, but I also get the "not marked" exception.

Comment: Using Shim NuGet package fixes the first issue, but stock serialization doesn't play nicely with Azure .NET backend (non-clr types don't get serialized; just null arrives at the AMS side). So it looks like I'm after DataContractSerializer

Comment: Worked for me. It's important `SerializableAttribute` to be in `System` namespace

Answer (score 2):

For .Net 4.6 and up the DataContract is no longer available to PCL. You need to add the Nuget package System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives/

Note for actual serialisation you'll probably also need an implementation such as System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml or a Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: I didn't know you can do that! Saved me a bunch of time and made my life way easier! Thanks!