# How to Host Portable Class Library Class Instance in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, webforms, viewstate

I have an ASP.NET Web-forms application with two projects: The main Web project and a [portable class library project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have the following code:

In the portable project I have an `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in the Default.aspx.cs page I have the following demo code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Item item = new Item();
    item.ID = 1;
    item.Name = "John";
    ViewState["MyKey"] = item;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
// Obviously I have a button named "Button1" on the page.
{
    if (ViewState["MyKey"] != null)
    {
        Item item = (Item)ViewState["MyKey"];
        Button1.Text = item.ID + " " + item.Name;
    }
}
```

Obviously that is causing the error:

> Type 'PortableProject.Item' in Assembly 'PortableProject,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
>   as serializable

While I'm aware of the problem and the expected solution, I'm not able to implement it. The solution is to provide the attribute `[Serializable]` to the `Item` class. However, this is not possible because the portable class library does not have `System.SerializableAttribute`. I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903262/portable-class-library-recommended-replacement-for-serializable) similar question. However, decorating the class with the `[DataContract]` attribute and the members with `[DataMember]` has not solved the problem (the same error kept showing). Apparently the view state serializes the object in a particular way that requires the functionality that the `[Serializable]` attribute provides. So, how to put an instance of `Item` in the View State without having the preceding error?

**EDIT**

I'm still looking for a solution. Obviously my portable project will be consumed by cross-platform environments, that's why I have to keep it a **portable** class library. Moreover, I wish to use the classes within that portable class library in my web forms pages (namely the ViewState object).

[This](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20viewstate%20DataContract) search appeared to be so promising but I still couldn't get a hold of a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Json.Newtonsoft to convert the object into a string.  Then use that string within the Viewstate.

Something like this should work.

```
 Item item = new Item();
    item.ID = 1;
    item.Name = "John";
    ViewState["MyKey"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
```