# Serialize object in UWP app

Tags: c#, serialization, uwp

I'm trying to pass an object over a `StreamSocket`, so i need to serialize it before i can do that.

I looked at the `BinaryFormatter`, but that doesn't seem to be available in UWP?
Any suggestions on how to serialize an object, and preferably in the most compact way.

Comment: HTH, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903628/815938

Comment: BinarySerializer from nuget might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serialize your own .NET objects; [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a very popular choice, but the built-in [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) should also work if you don't want any dependencies.

You cannot serialize any WinRT objects.

Comment: Ended up using `DataContractSerializer`, then i could serialize it as binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize an object to json, at first you have to add Newtonsoft.Json to your project.

To install Json.NET, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

> PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Then use this code to pass your object :

(Note: In this sample I suppose your server and client are the same and the port that you are using is: 1800.)

```
        try
        {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
            Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("127.0.0.1");
            string serverPort = "1800";
            socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
            var request = json;
            writer.WriteLine(request);
            writer.Flush();

            Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
            string response = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var err = e.Message;
            //Handle exception here.            
        }
```

Inform me if you have any other question.